# Understanding the basics of electromagnetic induction

Tags: electromagnetism, induction

Suppose two rings are kept facing each other and that one ring have some current which increases constantly. Will the other ring be attracted or repelled? Does this also depend on *how they are kept*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the current increases uniformly the flux would increase uniformly. As per Faraday's and Lenz's law the induced currents tend to oppose the change in flux. So currents would be induced in the opposite direction causing the two rings to repel.

Answer (score 0):

The result is an application of [Lenz's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law).

Comment: I know but what's answer